# How to generate keystore for Play 2 Framework?

Tags: playframework, openssl, playframework-2.0, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I would like to set `HTTPS` only for my application. For that, I'm using `LetsEncrypt` to generate my certificate and to be my `CA`.

LetsEncrypt generated these files for me:

```
root@myapp:/opt/letsencrypt# ll /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.company.coms/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 19 15:46 ./
drwx------ 3 root root 4096 Feb 19 15:46 ../
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   47 Feb 19 15:46 cert.pem -> ../../archive/myapp.company.coms/cert1.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   48 Feb 19 15:46 chain.pem -> ../../archive/myapp.company.coms/chain1.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   52 Feb 19 15:46 fullchain.pem -> ../../archive/myapp.company.coms/fullchain1.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   50 Feb 19 15:46 privkey.pem -> ../../archive/myapp.company.coms/privkey1.pem
```

[Reading Play 2 Framework documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ConfiguringHttps), they say this:

```
https.keyStore - The path to the keystore containing the private key and certificate, if not provided generates a keystore for you
https.keyStoreType - The key store type, defaults to JKS
https.keyStorePassword - The password, defaults to a blank password
https.keyStoreAlgorithm - The key store algorithm, defaults to the platforms default algorithm
```

An example of using these properties might be:

```
./start -Dhttps.port=9443 -Dhttps.keyStore=/path/to/keystore -Dhttps.keyStorePassword=changeme
```

Now that I have the key and the certificate generated by LetsEncrypt, how can I generate my keystore to be used by Play 2 Framework ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Here is the answer to your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38339977/how-to-configure-a-play-application-to-use-lets-encrypt-certificate

Comment: https://www.ravinderpayal.com/Free-SSL-Certificate-play-framework/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure a Play application to use Let's Encrypt certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38339977/how-to-configure-a-play-application-to-use-lets-encrypt-certificate)

Answer (score 1):

If you need `PKCS12` type (language-neutral way to store encrypted private keys and certificates):

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in ../../archive/myapp.company.coms/fullchain1.pem 
-inkey ../../archive/myapp.company.coms/privkey1.pem 
-out ../../archive/myapp.company.coms/keystore.p12 
-CAfile ../../archive/myapp.company.coms/cert1.pem 
-caname root
```

*(enter your preferred password 2 times or you can use parameter `-passout pass:your_password`)*

Your `pkcs12` will be located here:
`../../archive/myapp.company.coms/keystore.p12`
In your application use:
`https.keyStoreType=PKCS12`

If you need `JKS` then:
1. Make `pkcs12` (as described above)
2. Use:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore ../../archive/myapp.company.coms/keystore.p12 
-srcstoretype pkcs12 
-destkeystore ../../archive/myapp.company.coms/cert.jks 
-deststoretype jks
```

*(enter your preferred password 2 times or you can use parameter `-storepass your_password`)*
*(enter your password which you use for pkcs12 or you can use parameter `-srcstorepass your_password`)*

Your jks will be located here:
`../../archive/myapp.company.coms/cert.jks`
In your application use:
`https.keyStoreType=JKS`